# How to make pseudo class :invalid apply to an input AFTER submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I have created a form and decided to validate it with just HTML5 and some JS without any additional plugins. So all of my required inputs have `required` attribute.

Here is the CSS to make them look nice

```
input:invalid {
    border: 2px solid #c15f5f
}
```

It sets the border of the `invalid` inputs to red, even if they haven't been touched yet.

How to make `input:invalid` apply after clicking submit button, along with the error messages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a class to the form when the submit-button was clicked and adjust your CSS selector so it only matches the input fields in a submitted form:

```js
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
 document.getElementById("testForm").className="submitted";
});
```

```css
form.submitted input:invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="testForm">
<input type="text" required>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitButton">
</form>
```

Comment: It would be better to add a `submit` event listener on the form instead of a click listener on the button, so that if the form is submitted by pressing return in the input (or any other means), then this would still work. You could also not have to do a second selector: `document.getElementById("testForm").addEventListener("submit", function(){
 this.className="submitted";
})`

Comment: @idlefingers except that the OP is using HTML5 form validation which doesn't fire the submit event.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Thomas' solution and idlefinger's comment, I would suggest listening for the [HTML5 invalid event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/invalid_event), which fires prior to the submit event.

```js
// save all form controls as variable
var inputs = document.getElementById("your-form").elements;

// Iterate over the form controls
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

  inputs[i].addEventListener("invalid", function(){
    document.getElementById("your-form").className="submitted";

  });
};
```

```css
form input {
    background: #eee;
}

form.submitted input:invalid {
    background: #ff3b3b;
}
```

```html
<form id="your-form">
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
input:invalid:not([value='']) {
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #c15f5f;
}
```

but I prefer using box-shadow rather than border or outline (the default)

Comment: This is not a solution, since it still shows an invalid state on initial loading.