# Input type email - remove default style

Tags: html, css

I have an `<input type="emai">` on my html page.

When the email is not valid, the input get `:invalid CSS pseudo-classes` and the border became red.

Because I use a custom style input that thing makes it ugly.

How I can disable that red border and all default effect(if there are others) from `:invalid`?

Comment: input:invalid {border: none;}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation in HTML5. :invalid classe after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576190/validation-in-html5-invalid-classe-after-submit)

Comment: @LuísP.A. It doesn't work. It remove my custom border, but that red thing is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple pseudo classes on an input but the most important three are `:active` , `:focus` and in this case `:invalid` . Active is when you have clicked on the input but doesn't leave your mouse. Focus is when your curser is blinking inside the input and invalid you know.

Here's the code that you can use. Also the border you are talking about can be the `outline` property and is in the focus state.

Here's the code that you can modify accordingly.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica, Montserrat, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input:active {
  background: rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.1);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.1);
}

.input:invalid {
  border-color: black;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="email" />
```

**EDIT:**

Firefox somehow seems to apply a `box-shadow` of red color on `:invalid` style. Just add `box-shadow:none;` in `:invalid` style and you will have no that border kindy thing.

Comment: As you can see(in snippet) that red thing is still there if I type an invalid email.

Comment: I can't see any red border in the snippet. Probably you might have some different browser than chrome or it might be outdated. You have something different on your device. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 74.0. Here is an image with what I see: https://i.imgur.com/iZ2Uhkx.png

Comment: Okay, I got it, Firefox kind of seems to apply a box-shadow of red color on an invalid style, its not a border, its a shadow, just add box-shadow: none; on :invalid state.

Comment: I've edited the code above, just run directly here, the snippet

Comment: Thank you! There is no way to disable this default css from browser? I ask this because maybe other browser have other default css for `invalid`.

Comment: Browsers have this default styling built in their actual binary and usually, they don't provide you with options to edit such defaults. However, you can use an extension (I am not aware of any) that can help you with this. Extensions have this capability that they can interact with the page code.