# Lazy Evaluation of the :invalid selector

Tags: html, css, forms, validation

Normally the :invalid selector is evaluated instantly : The element will be styled immediately with :invalid for example if a value is required as soon as the page loads:

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
<p> Go red only after I focused and blurred away </p>
  <input required placeholder="you must type something" />
</form>
```

Would there be a workaround for this so that the evaluation happens only after the user interacts with the form? (typically, after the first focus / blur).
I understand this is standard browser implementation behavior so we're likely looking for a workaround here.

Minimal JS is OK although I don't want to do JS validation.

Comment: There will be no quick workaround: it's either instant validation or you need JS to access the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#the_constraint_validation_api). With 'minimal' JS you might get problems with *accessibility* and screen readers which users often rely on the step-by-step instant validation. This page [A Guide To Accessible Form Validation](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/02/guide-accessible-form-validation/) discusses *instant*, *after* and *submit* validation in relation to *accessibility*, with examples.

Comment: I suspect this is what you are looking for (or end up implementing): [A Guide To Accessible Form Validation: SUBMIT VALIDATION](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/02/guide-accessible-form-validation/#submit-validation).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576190/validation-in-html5-invalid-classe-after-submit or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619497/how-to-make-pseudo-class-invalid-apply-to-an-input-after-submitting-a-form or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021801/inputinvalid-css-rule-is-applied-on-page-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely. Instead of setting the `required` attribute prematurely, you can mark items with something (a `required` `class` in this case) and program the events you want to trigger the adding of the `required` attribute (`blur` in this case):

```js
function myBlur() {
    this.setAttribute("required", null);
}

function myFocus() {
    this.removeAttribute("required");
}

for (let item of document.getElementsByClassName("required")) {
    item.addEventListener("blur", myBlur);
    item.addEventListener("focus", myFocus);
}
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="required" placeholder="you must type something" />
</form>
```

In the example above I'm adding the `required` attribute on `blur` and removing it on `focus`, so it will not yell at users if they are removing the content while the item is being focused, but will be complaining whenever the item loses focus while not having a value.

Comment: And when they click the submit button when they never interact with the element?

Comment: @epascarello at the button validation's end the required attribute can be added as well. Here I focused on the minimum for the sake of brevity, but we can surely add further handlers and logic, depending on the logic on the site. Inside the validator one can call `setAttribute` for items having a class of `required` inside the `form` to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to combine multiple pseudo-classes to achieve the result, as explained [here](https://www.bram.us/2021/01/28/form-validation-you-want-notfocusinvalid-not-invalid/).

Here's an example (adapted from [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/ExNYBOK)) which shows the red border only if the value is invalid (in this case less than 3 characters in length).

```css
:root {
  --color-invalid: red;
  --color-valid: green;
}

.error-message {
    display: none;
}

/* Used for the demo to show that the input changes status (eg. passing from an invalid to a valid email address) */
input {
  outline: none;
}


/* Invalid state */

input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  border-color: var(--color-invalid);
}


/* Valid state */

input:not(:placeholder-shown):valid {
  border-color: var(--color-valid);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="name" type="text" minlength="3" maxlength="20" required placeholder="test min/max length input" />
</form>
```

Comment: quite cool! but if your only requirement is filling out any number of characters in the input, the error style will never appear, right? (or am I missing something?)

Comment: this might also work when the condition is specific (e.g. min/max values present) but not for the basic scenario where the only requirement is to just 'type something' .

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos I've updated the example which now uses an input of type text with `minlength`, the error appears as soon as the user starts typing and changes to status valid after 3 or more characters are entered. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: No, any number of characters is accepted. I think this workaround works well for emails or cases where more specific rules are required.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Ok got it! Sorry I did not understand that requirement. In that case this won't work as a solution.